# Javascript Groovy button doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've made buttons at the bottom of this page: http://www.constructionline.co.uk/static/acclaim/index.html

But they don't act as links in IE. I'm using IE 11. Can any one help?

Comment: Just for you: your buttons do not work in IE9 either

Comment: Yep - I'd not be very bother if it didn't work in IE 8 or lower... but I'm using 11! I can't see why this wouldn't work :(

Comment: IE11 gives a bunch of HTML warnings, doubled head and body etc. Also there's a JS error in Code.js, line 1140, "brs is not defined.".

Comment: @Teemu You're right. But I think removingthe doubled head and body section will not have any effect.

Comment: Fixed the head / body error - no idea how to fix the other... how would this impact on an unrelated element? Please note I'm a beginner.

Comment: Maybe, but removing the JS error might have an effect. That snippet sniffs used browser, probably `brs` should be `ua`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `<input>` with type=button won't work as you're expecing on it's own. The only reason it works in other browsers is that it's wrapped in an `<a>`. This isn't correct HTML and I believe IE's behaviour is correct, whereas other browsers are being a bit more flexible.

What you could do, is remove the `<a>` and add an onclick event to the `<input>`, like:

```
<input type="button" name="Benefits" class="groovybutton" value="Find out more benefits &gt;&gt;" onclick="location.href = 'acclaim/acclaimbenefits.html'" onmouseover="goLite(this.form.name,this.name)" onmouseout="goDim(this.form.name,this.name)" style="background-color: rgb(169, 34, 22); border-color: rgb(169, 34, 22);">
```

The problem then is that browsers without javascript support won't be able to follow the link.

Really, I don't think you need the `<input>` at all, you should be able to just do this:

```
<a href="acclaim/acclaimbenefits.html" class="ac-no-arrow">Find out more benefits &gt;&gt;</a>
```

Your goLite() and goDim() javascript could probably be replaced with CSS

Comment: I've got the same theory. After I added the onclick attribute on the button, it did work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's appreciated - I'll give this a go

Comment: Ahhhh! So this fix works... BUT, rather that going to ...line.co.uk/static/acclaim/acclaimbenefits.html it goes to ...line.co.uk/static/acclaim/acclaim/acclaimbenefits.html. I really hate IE SO much!

Comment: Change the href to '/static/acclaim/acclaimbenefits.html' or 'acclaimbenefits.html'. If the URL is relative (as per the second example) it's location will depend on the URL of the current page. If my answer solved your original problem, please mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Thanks, I tried both of these: 'acclaimbenefits.html' works in IE but not Firefox / Chrome and '/static/acclaim/acclaimbenefits.html' worked in Chrome / Firefox, but not IE... sorry to be a pain on Friday :(

Comment: You have `<base href="http://www.constructionline.co.uk/static/">` and  `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.constructionline.co.uk/static/acclaim/">` in your `<head>` which may be confusing things. IE seems to be using the canonical URL as the 'base' (or ignoring both), whereas Chrome is using the base...